# How to add PayPal donate button to my free WordPress blog

Tags: paypal, wordpress.com

I am looking to add a PayPal donate button on my free wordpress.com blog. I am not sure whether -

1. This is possible and allowable.
2. If it is allowable what do I need to do to make it workable and any tips that people would like to share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, PayPal provides information on how to create a donate button on [this page](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/donate_step_1/).

**Short summary**:

1. Login to your PayPal account and go to the PayPal button creation page
2. Enter the payment details for your organization
3. Set up the look and feel of the button (optional)
4. Set the currency and how donators can pay (optional)
5. Associate email address with transaction instead of merchant id (optional)

**Prerequisite**: Assumes you have a PayPal Business or Premier Account

Wikihow also has a [short guide](https://www.wikihow.com/Set-up-a-PayPal-Button-for-Donations) on setting up a donation button.

Comment: ah, ouch don't think I have done that. thank you all the same, will find out more.